# Странный крестик в уточнении знака

Tags: дефект, локализация, дизайн

Смотрю [профиль](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218984/aaa?tab=topactivity) и вижу такую штуку:

[image: скриншот]

По-моему, крестик рядом с фразой

> необходим положительный баланс вопросов

находится где-то не там.

Comment: По-моему, крестик где надо. А вот подпись к нему...

Comment: А верхний крестик по-моему не нужен вовсе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас выглядит одновременно и ровнее, и кривее:

> [image: знак]

Положение улучшилось, но вот шрифт и размер иконки зачем-то увеличились.

Завёл баг на MSE: [Issues in badge progress info block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299337/339911)

Comment: Эк вопрос на MSE заминусовали-то.

Comment: @Squidward вообще шайтаны, как будто считают, что и так сойдёт. Интересно, есть ли у них какой аналог Вовочки из тридесятого царства.

Answer (score 1):

Подобные проблемы уже встречались на сайте. Связаны они с длиной текста после перевода. И как показывает практика, решать такие проблемы приходится исключительно изменением перевода. То есть, убедить разработчиков исправить дизайн, чтобы одинаково хорошо смотрелись строки разной длины, очень маловероятное событие.

Строки, которые можно увидеть в упомянутом окне имеют две формы:

- need positive question record / необходим положительный баланс вопросов
- positive question record / положительный баланс вопросов

Для первой из них рисуется серый крестик, для второй зеленая галочка. Таким образом слово "необходим" не так уж и необходимо для понимания сути (всё очевидно по иконке). И его можно убрать. Дополнительно, я бы изменил в описании слово "голосов" на "вопросов", т.к. речь о выполнении некоторого условия, [отражающего полезность вопросов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290545/339911).

Comment: Нет, там именно о вопросах, насколько я помню...

Comment: @Qwertiy о голосах на вопросах. Я так и написал. Или Вы о чём-то другом?

Comment: Да, верстка там явно делалась пьяным бабуином под спидами ИМХО. Запилить что ли расширение с правкой багов?

Comment: _"Дополнительно я бы изменил слово "вопросов" на "голосов", т.к. речь идет всё же о голосах, хоть и на вопросах."_ - об этом. Вроде бы голоса там не считаются?

Comment: @Qwertiy а что считается?

Comment: @alexolut, вроде бы число вопросов с положительным рейтингом минус число вопросов с отрицательным рейтингом (в том числе и закрытых, и удалённых) минус число закрытых вопросов с любым рейтингом (в том числе удалённых) минус число удалённых вопрсов. (Получится что удалённый закрытый вопрос вычтется трижды.) Хотя могу ошибаться и такой подсчёт где-то в другом месте.

Comment: @Qwertiy действительно. [Не всё так просто](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290546/339911).

Comment: @alexolut, `≥ 0.5` o_O

Comment: @Qwertiy это лучше, чем 0.33, но хуже, чем 0.7

Comment: @alexolut, почему бы не просто >0?

Comment: @Qwertiy например, чтобы при 3 вопросах, если есть один закрытый и удаленный из них, то проверка не срабатывала. Собственно кто-то решил взять такую границу. Не вижу тут каких-то серьезных проблем.