# Крестик уведомлений выровнен неровно

Tags: дефект, дизайн

[image: скриншот 1]

[image: скриншот 2]

[image: скриншот 3]

Comment: Надо бы ещё с финальной точкой разобраться.

Comment: Разве "выровнен неровно" не то же самое, что "не выровнен"? )

Comment: Дайте отдохнуть крестику. Он устал и, возможно, в депрессии.

Comment: @alexolut, с какой точкой?

Comment: В конце текста которая.

Comment: @alexolut, так она же в конце - что не так?

Comment: В первом сообщении её нет.

Comment: @alexolut, давай из всех удалим?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у некоторых попапов появилась новая кнопка закрытия (имхо, не нужная вовсе). Посмотреть можно [тут](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5516/176217), например. Вполне вероятно, что это тот самый крест.

Comment: Надо бы согласовать с [другой ситуацией](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4640/176217). Хотя описание метки и упомянутый здесь однострочный попап всё же разные сущности.

Comment: @alexolut, точка перед смайлом не ставится :) И перед крестиком - тоже))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61204/discussion-between-alexolut-and-qwertiy).